# Weird pipe shut off issue

Tags: plumbing, shutoff

This is a really weird issue and I am wondering if this is normal or if something is messed up with my plumbing.

Anyways, twice now I have had to shut off the hot and cold water in different areas of my house in order to replace something. I then reconnect the cold and turn it on to test it before moving on to the hot water only to have water come out of the hot water pipe as if I had turned it on instead of the cold.

Hope someone out there has an answer to this.

Thanks!

Comment: The cold water supply pressurizes the water heater. Do you have a shutoff before or after the hot water tank?

Comment: "Hot water pipe"? what exactly is that. Is that a kitchen, bath or shower faucet? Does it have two valves or one mixing valve?